# The parameterized query '(@QuotationNo varchar(),@AgencyName varchar(),@ContractS' expects the parameter '@QuotationNo', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework with repository pattern trying to access a stored procedure.

Generic repository pattern

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedureFunction(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    return _entities.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters).ToList();
}
```

with this code:

```
var reportFilterDb =
                _iGenericReportProcRepository.ExecuteStoredProcedureFunction("StoredProcedureReport @QuotationNo, @AgencyName, @ContractStartDate, @ContractEndDate, @contractTerm",
                    new SqlParameter("QuotationNo", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = filter.QuotationNo },
                    new SqlParameter("AgencyName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = filter.AgencyName },
                    new SqlParameter("ContractStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = filter.FContractStartDate },
                    new SqlParameter("ContractEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = filter.FContractEndDate },
                    new SqlParameter("contractTerm", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = filter.Term }
                    ).ToList();
```

Here is the stored procedure structure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedureReport]
    @QuotationNo VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @AgencyName VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @ContractStartDate DATETIME NULL,
    @ContractEndDate DATETIME NULL,
    @contractTerm INT NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    SELECT 
        con.Contract_AgencyName, con.Contract_EndDate, 
        con.Contract_Id AS 'ContractId', con.Contract_QuoteNo,  
        con.Contract_StartDate,
        ConSer.ContractService_Id, ConSer.Description,
        ConSer.MonthlyUnitPrice, ConSer.OrderEndDate, 
        ConSer.OrderStartDate, ConSer.OrderTermMonths,
        ConSer.Quantity, ConSer.TotalPrice
    FROM 
        Contract AS con 
    JOIN
        ContractService AS ConSer ON con.Contract_Id = ConSer.Contract_Id
    WHERE 
        (con.Contract_QuoteNo = @QuotationNo OR @QuotationNo IS NULL)
        AND (con.Contract_AgencyName = @AgencyName OR @AgencyName IS NULL)
        AND (con.Contract_StartDate = @ContractStartDate OR @ContractStartDate IS NULL)
        AND (con.Contract_EndDate = @ContractEndDate OR @ContractEndDate IS NULL)
        AND (ConSer.OrderTermMonths = @contractTerm OR @contractTerm IS NULL)
GO
```

I am not able to execute the result getting the error:

> The parameterized query '(@QuotationNo varchar(), @AgencyName varchar(), @ContractS' expects the parameter '@QuotationNo', which was not supplied

Comment: Shouldn't `SqlParameter("QuotationNo"` be `SqlParameter("@QuotationNo"` ?

Comment: Didn't work. same error

Comment: What does the `ExecuteStoreProcFunction` do? Are you using `ExecuteScalar` or another method to execute the procedure?

Comment: What is “ExecuteStoreProcFunction”?  Is it successfully applying the parameters?  If the same error persists then that suggests not.

Comment: OP man you need to do more research and less asking for answers on SO. You've made daily (or more) posts for the past month. We're not debuggers and this isn't a code writing service. Read this article and update your code to the proper specifications: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `filter.QuotationNo` is `null`, the parameter *will not be added*, which is a horrible API experience.

Try instead:

```
 .Value = (object)filter.QutationNo ?? DBNull.Value
```

(etc for all the parameters). Alternatively, consider a tool like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) which will do such things automatically:

```
_connection.Execute("StoredProcedureReport", new { // or Query<T> etc
    filter.QuotationNo,
    filter.AgencyName,
    ContractStartDate = filter.FContractStartDate,
    ContractEndDate = filter.FContractEndDate,
    contractTerm = filter.Term,
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
var reportFilterDb =
                _iGenericReportProcRepository.ExecuteStoredProcedureFunction("EXEC StoredProcedureReport @QuotationNo, @AgencyName, @ContractStartDate, @ContractEndDate, @contractTerm",
                    new SqlParameter("@QuotationNo", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = (object)filter.QuotationNo ?? DBNull.Value },
                    new SqlParameter("@AgencyName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = (object)filter.AgencyName ?? DBNull.Value },
                    new SqlParameter("@ContractStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = (object)filter.FContractStartDate ?? DBNull.Value },
                    new SqlParameter("@ContractEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = (object)filter.FContractEndDate ?? DBNull.Value  },
                    new SqlParameter("@contractTerm", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (object)filter.Term ?? DBNull.Value  }
                    ).ToList();
```